# Getting a field from another django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

How can I get the field pto from emplyees app and use it in the permission app.

employee/models.py

```
class Employee(AbstractUser):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    pto = models.IntegerField(default=20)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, related_name='+')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

permission/models.py

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('PENDING', 'PENDING'),
        ('DENIED', 'DENIED'),
        ('ACCEPTED', 'ACCEPTED')
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lorem')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=STATUS, default=STATUS[0][0])
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

sorry if a was not clear, thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your question doesn't tell us.

Answer (score 0):

add this to class Permissions model

```
from yourproject.apps.employee.models import Employee

class Permission(models.Model):
    ..........

    def get_pto(self):
        return int(self.user.pto) # if it's floating point number then change int to float
```

now you can use `get_pto` in your html, `{{ form.get_pto }}`

Sorry if this is not what you are looking for, let me know clearly and I will try to answer if I can.